# See Which JavaScript File Is Applying a Style to an Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I am trying to find which JavaScript is applying "display: inline" to an image element. As you can see by the attached picture, "display: none" is getting overridden but I have no idea where "display: inline" is coming from:

[image]

The source is a PHP file with many .js files. I've tried using breakpoints in my Chrome developer tools but lose them when I reload the page. Any ideas how I can spot the JS code that's applying "display: inline"?

Comment: It is coming from a `style` attribute that is written directly in the HTML of the element (i.e. `<p style="display:none">`). That's what the section `element.style` means.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: That's also where changes made via `element.style.display = "inline"` are shown.

Comment: @Scott That's what i thought, too, but there is no such inline style in the element. That's why I believe it must be getting applied by JavaScript.

Comment: _"there is no such inline style in the element"_ At original `html` and after `.js` files are loaded?

Comment: if you post your html and javascript we may help you in the better way.

Comment: If the element has an id or class associated with it, try to search the js files with that and see if you can find the file where it is being applied.

Comment: @poushy The element has no ID or class assigned it. The JavaScript is targeting it using a different method.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me in Chrome:

1. Open the page
2. Right-click the element and choose Inspect Element
3. In the DOM view, right-click the element in the DOM tree
4. At the bottom of the menu (for me) choose **Break On > attribute modifications**
   *(later, when you want to remove this, it's listed under DOM breakpoints)*
5. If the modification has already happened, hit refresh

When I do that, the breakpoint stops the code as of the line setting `.style.display = "inline"` on the element (even on page refresh).

My element is defined by markup, not added by code later, so if yours is added by code later, the DOM breakpoint may not survive page refresh.

If the DOM breakpoint **doesn't** survive page refresh for some reason, but the element is defined by markup, then:

1. Modify the page markup so that **immediately** after the closing tag of the element, you have `<script>debugger;</script>`, like this:

   ```
   <div>This is the element</div>
   <script>debugger;</script>
   <div>The next element...</div>
   ```

   *(Normally we don't litter `script` tags all over our HTML, but this is a debugging session.)*
2. Open dev tools
3. Open the page; it will stop on the `debugger` statement above
4. Switch to the DOM view and find the element there (it'll be right near the bottom)
5. Right-click it and choose **Break On > attribute modifications**
6. Hit the Resume arrow to allow things to continue

That should let you set the DOM breakpoint in time to catch whatever's modifying it.

Finally: If the element is added by script code, you'll have to find the code adding it (blech) and set a breakpoint just after it's added so you can pick up with Step #4 in the second list above.

Comment: Even if this doesn't solve the OP's issue, it's a debugging technique no-one can be without.

Comment: I've tried this. The problem is when I refresh the page, Break On > attribute modifications gets unchecked, thus it doesn't break as it should. Any way to get around this?

Comment: @GTSJoe: I thought of a way, which I was just adding; see the new bit above.

Comment: T.J. This allows me to add Break On > Modifications, but when I switch to the "Sources" tab in Chrome Dev Tools, it's not highlighting or showing which JS file is making the changes. Isn't it supposed go step-by-step, showing which code is taking effect?

Comment: @GTSJoe: For me, with it breaks on the modification, it goes to Sources and highlights the line assigning to a property on `style`. I'm afraid you'll have to create a [mcve] by paring down what you have until it's small enough to be shareable. (By which time, you'll probably have found the issue.)